# Fast batch insert/update with SQL Server 2008 and BCP

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm not a good SQL programmer, I've got only the basics, but I've heard of some BCP thing for fast data loading. I've searched the internet and it seems to be a command-line only utility, and not something you can use in code.

The thing is, I want to be able to make very fast inserts and updates in a SQL Server 2008 database. I would like to have a function in the database that would accept:

- The name of the table I want to execute an insert/update operation against
- The names of the columns I'll be feeding data to
- The data in a CSV format or something that SQL can read stupid-fast
- A flag indicating weather the function should perform an insert or update operation

This function would then read this CSV string and genarate the necessary code for inserting/updating the table.

I would then write code in C# to call that function passing it the table name, column names, a list of objects serialized as a CSV string and the insert/update flag.

As you can see, this is intended to be both fast and generic, suitable for any project dealing with large amounts of data, and thus a candidate to my company's framework.

Am I thinking right? Is this a good idea? Can I use that BCP thing, and is it suitable to every case?

As you can see, I need some directions on this... thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How many rows are you inserting/updating?

Comment: Well, it is usualy something around 10,000 but sometimes it gets to 500,000 or even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, look at [SQLBulkCopy](http://SQLBulkCopy). It's what SSIS uses in the background.

For true [bcp](http://SQLBulkCopy)/[BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx), you'd need bulkadmin rights which may not be allowed

Comment: "you'd need bulkadmin rights" - And it's best not to do wacky security things when you're building a framework for something.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about the SqlBulkCopy class. Looks like it's the right thing for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Sam: yep, or may not be allowed in your shop. KISS etc :-)

Comment: SqlBulkCopy needs something like a DataTable or an IDataReader, and here's a link to an implementation of IDataReader to read from an IList: http://www.csvreader.com/posts/generic_list_datareader.php

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using SQL Server Integrated Services (SSIS). It's designed to do exactly what you describe. It is very fast. You can insert data on a transactional basis. And you can set it up to run on a schedule. And much more.